# how to fix linux application paging error?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

My program sometimes die.

like this:

> [4]+  Segmentation fault      ./Application

This problem appears randomly.
but this program can't attach gdb.

However, there are sure things I have found out in the log.
Before the program dies, It show me an log.

> [ 5191.986522] [00000071] *pgd=00000000f0643003, *pud=00000000ec089003, *pmd=0000000000000000

what is it?

pgd, pud, is always change. maybe it is address.

5191 is always change too. but what is it?

0071 isn't change. what is it?

I know pgd, pmd, pud is linux pageing keyword.
but I don't know another things.

program is too big. It use many technology that dbus, multi thread, sqlite3, socket, file stream.

Please let me know what I need to do now.

I need idea.

Comment: This is a common symptom of a buggy program, usually caused by trying to dereference an invalid pointer or NULL pointer.  The first thing you should do is run your program in a debugger and reproduce the fault there, so that you can get a stack-trace showing where in the code the program crashed.  Another option is to run your program under `valgrind`, which can give you more information about where and how the program went wrong.  If neither of those work, then you'll have to debug the hard way, e.g. by adding temporary `printf()` calls to your code and watching what they print.

Comment: Btw 5191.xxxxx is probably number-of-seconds-since-system-boot.  The other values are likely locations of the bad pointer(s) in memory-space -- they probably won't be very helpful without the aid of a debugger.

Comment: This is not how someone would go about figuring out and fix bugs in C++ code. Trying to make sense of register dumps (which is what this is) is a complete waste of time. Instead, one should learn how to use a debugger, and how to use static code analysis tools. Even better, learn safe programming practices and techniques that makes common logical bugs logically impossible. The best way to avoid these kinds of bugs is to make it logically impossible for them to happen, by learning techniques that avoid them, as much as possible.

Comment: You got a kernel crash. I would recommend to study a bit how kernel Oops:es are look like and how to read and decode them